# Find invalid push tokens for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, node.js, express, push-notification

I am developing a mobile application having push notification feature [Android and iOS].I am using [node-gcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) and [node-apn](https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn) for sending push.

Is there any way to  find  tokens are invalid or not (iOS/Android registration token) ,so that I can remove them from my database?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it in my project:

**[Android]**

If you pass array of tokens to *node-gcm* in response you'll get an array with length equals tokens count. That array contains response for each token - success or error. Based on error you can decide whether to delete token or not:

```
// This is response from Google
response.results.map((item,index) => {
    if (item.error) {
        // If Google doesn't recognize token I don't need to keep it anymore
        if (item.error === 'NotRegistered') {
            failedTokens.push(androidTokens[index]);
        } else {
            logger.error(`Push notification was not sent because: ${item.error}`);
        }
    }
});

failedTokens.map(token => {
    this.deleteDeviceToken('android', appName, token);
});
```

**[iOS]**

I have something similar for iOS. But worth noting that we use HTTP2 APN. So below solution will work for you only if you use HTTP2 for APN too:

```
// Response from Apple
response.failed.map(failure => {
    if (failure.error) {
        logger.error(`Error during sending notification: ${JSON.stringify(failure.error)}`);
    } else {
        // If APN returned HTTP 400 with status BadDeviceToken or HTTP 410 with status Unregistered
        // then delete invalid tokens.
        if (failure.response.reason === 'BadDeviceToken' || failure.response.reason === 'Unregistered') {
            this.deleteDeviceToken('ios', appName, failure.device);
        } else {
            logger.error(`Push notification was not sent because: ${failure.response.reason}`);
        }
    }
});
```